# The use of the phrase "that is all" in context

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please if used the phrase correctly in the following context.

> Person 1: How is this bottle called in English?
>
> Person 2: Water bottle
>
> Person 1: and **that is all**?

What I want to convey by that phrase is that person 1 is surprised by the fact that the bottle is simply called a water bottle, and there is no any specific name to the bottle. I doubt that that phrase was right in that context. I just translated it word for word from my native language. Tell me please what is the natural way to convey the meaning in English.

Comment: **What** is this bottle called? No, you are not using it "and that is all" correctly.  Idiomatic would be "And that's the **only** name for it?"

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Did you mean *and that is all?* as asking whether those two words are truly enough to describe the type of bottle, or whether there are any other (different) terms aside from *water bottle* to describe the bottle?

Comment: The first option: whether two words are trully enough to describe the type of bottle

Comment: "Person 1: and nothing else?"

Comment: Would it be the phrase "that is it" be equivallent to the pjrase "and nothing else" in the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**and that is all?** can be paraphrased as "And *is there* nothing else?"  or "Is that the full extent of it?"

> Why did you set up this meeting?
>   -- I wanted to talk about the microwave in the cafeteria.
>   And that's all?  Couldn't you have sent me an email?

Or

> He has been charged with bank-fraud and possession of narcotics.
>   --And that is all?
>   And he has over $10,000 in unpaid parking tickets.

If you ask me

> What's this called in English?

and I reply

> It's called a *syringe*.

It would **not** be idiomatic for you to reply back to me

> And that's the extent of it?

Why? Because you've asked for a name, not for an explanation, or a list. You've not asked for anything with "extent".

Now, if you were to ask instead:

> What are all of the words for this thing in English?

and I say

> It's a bottle opener.

Then you might retort:

> And that's *all*?

or

> And that's *it*?

Comment: And how exactly doesn't that fit the context? Despite the asker's "and there is no any specific name to the bottle", I think they meant to say "there's nothing that'd further specify this type of bottle" – *Is that really its full name?*.

Comment: @userr2684291: The question **and that is all?** is existential. Names for things are not existential. Idiomatic would be **only**. or *Are there **other** names for it?*   The usage is not ungrammatical, but it is not idiomatic.

Comment: I think native speakers would actually ask *And that's it? Just "water bottle"?*, perhaps with some emphasis on the word *water*. I'd say *And that's all?* is essentially equivalent. I can't read minds but I think they didn't mean to ask about other terms to identify the type of bottle.

Comment: **And that's it?** would be idiomatic here, I agree, but **And that's it?** is not the idiomatic equivalent of **And that's all?** in this particular context. Not a huge difference, but were talking about what is idiomatic in context. If you disagree, please give an answer of your own.